# jsPDF package is downloading as an empty PDF for html content in react (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I am using `jsPDF` to download HTML content as pdf in react. I can download a pdf file, but it is showing an empty page only. If I use `text` for download like this

```
const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", true);
    doc.text("hello", 10, 20);
    doc.save();
```

it is downloading with the content "hello". But I use `html` to download,

```
const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", true);
var elem: any = document.getElementById("test");
doc.html(elem, {
      callback: (doc: any) => {
        doc.save(`Test.pdf`);
      }
    });
```

It is downloading as an empty page only. Since the tag changed to `fromHTML` to `html`, I need help on this. (previous discussions are a long time ago happened).